# after generating an SSL certificate and a new private key, how do you actually test them out and encrypt fake plaintext?

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, keytool

*2022_public.cer* is a certificate that is about to expire and must be replaced by a new one (*2023_public.cer*).

*secret.bin* is password-protected and contains the private key corresponding to *2022_public.cer*.  I know this password and will be using it in the steps below.

The task is to generate a new private / public key pair and update *secret.bin*.  Here are the steps I took:

(1)Use the keytool command to figure out alias and CN of private key that is about to expire

```
keytool -list -v -keystore secret.bin
```

from the output I noted down the alias to be "*my_alias_1*" and the CN is "*my_cn_ssl.net*"

(2) use the keytool command to generate a new public/private keypair using a slightly modified alias and the same CN:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias my_alias_2 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
    -dname "CN=my_cn_ssl.net, OU=Sec, O=Company, L=miami, ST=Florida, C=US" -keystore private.jks
```

is generates a file called "*private.jks*".

(3) use keytool to create a certificate signing request using *private.jks* generated in step 2.

```
keytool -certreq -alias my_alias_2 -file public.csr -keystore private.jks
```

it generates a file called *public.csr*

(4) submit *public.csr* to a Certificate Authority, and in return you will get *2023_public.cer* as desired.

(5) Finally, update the *secret.bin* with the *private.jks* you generated in step 2

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore private.jks -destkeystore secret.bin
```

Question : how do I verify *2023_public.cer* and *secret.bin* play nice with each other (i.e. how do I test SSL / TLS communication using these two files?). Is there a script I can run that will verify this for me? Is there an openssl command I can run to actually encrypt some test plain text and decrypt it to verify it works correctly?

Comment: *2 Is there an openssl command I can run to actually encrypt some test plain text and decrypt it to verify it works correctly?"* - certificates are used in TLS not for encryption, but for authentication.

Comment: Just try to use the new setup as an SSL server or client certificate, in the same way the old one was. If it works, and it will if your steps are correct, you're done.

Comment: Not programming or development, but after step 4 you must import the cert from the CA PLUS its root and any intermediate aka chain cert(s) into the keystore where you did the genkeypair in step 2 (private.jks) BEFORE using it for SSL/TLS. Also if this is a _webserver_ accessed by browsers, or some but not all other kinds of SSL/TLS application, getting the CN (CommonName) correct is not enough, you must have the SAN (SubjectAltName) correctly identify the server; see rfcs 2818 and 6125 for a start.

Comment: @user207421 - are there any steps describing how this can be done? I think that's exactly what I need to do.  If you can point me to a website that shows how I can test secret.bin and 2023_public.cer to verify they work , that would be great.  I just want to setup the most simplest client and web server to run this test.